# State increasing +40 instead of +20

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to increase each item in `sliderValues` +20 when clicking Increase Volume.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

export const App = ({ name }) => {
  const [sliderValues, setSliderValues] = useState([50, 50, 50, 50, 50]); // Initial slider values

  const audios = [
    { src: '/fire.mp3', icon: '\\f06d' },
    { src: '/crickets.mp3', icon: '\\e4d0' },
  ];

  const increaseVolume = () => {
    audios.forEach((audioRef, index) => {
      setSliderValues((prevValues) =>
        prevValues.map((prevValue) => {
          console.log(prevValue); // Log the previous value
          return prevValue + 20;
        })
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={increaseVolume}>Increase Volume</button>
      {/* Displaying the slider values */}
      <ul>
        {sliderValues.map((value, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{value}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

But right now, the items are increasing by +40. I think it's because there are two loops (`forEach` and `map`) and the +20 is being applied twice. But I'm not very sure how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Current output:

```
90
90
90
90
90
```

Desired output:

```
70
70
70
70
70
```

Working code on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-oydz5h?file=src%2FApp.tsx).

Comment: you are running twice the `setSliderValues` function because of the `audios.forEach` loop.  Every time you increase the value by `20`

Comment: Why run the loop on `audios` and for each iteration of the loop call `setSliderValues`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the first `forEach` since you're not doing anything with the audio's here.

Change the `increaseVolume` function to:

```
const increaseVolume = (index) => {
    setSliderValues((prevValues) =>
        prevValues.map((prevValue) => prevValue + 20)
    );
};
```

---

Updated Demo:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = ({ name }) => {

    const [sliderValues, setSliderValues] = useState([50, 50, 50, 50, 50]); // Initial slider values

    const increaseVolume = (index) => {
        setSliderValues((prevValues) =>
            prevValues.map((prevValue) => prevValue + 20)
        );
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={increaseVolume}>Amplify Audio</button>
            {/* Displaying the slider values */}
            <ul>
                {sliderValues.map((value, index) => (
                    <li key={index}>{value}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```